# Android studio -- how to include resource file in Java package using gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an android project which requires to include a non-java resource file to included in the final package with Java class.

If you are using Eclipse, it is very easy, just put the non-Java resource file in the same package of Java classes, Eclipse will automatically copy the resource file to the destination.

I tried the same method in Android Studio, which uses Gradle for building, but it doesn't pack the resource file in the final Java class package.  I have no control over how to read the resource file, it must use class.getResourceAsStream() to read the resource file.

Is there any way to pack resource file in Java package in the final product? Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: In your app's directory, go to `src/main/res` and place it in the appropriate directory (e.g., `values` for XML). If your resource is a file (e.g., a `.js` file), place it in `src/main/assets` and call it like `file:///android_asset/index.html` (or maybe `assets:///index.html`).

Comment: Eh, I have no control over how to use this resource file, actually, a Java class extends a 3rd party library, which assumes the resource file should be in the same package of this class, calling this getResourceAsStream() method of this class.  So I need to pack the resource file alongside with the bytecode class in the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Create a java resources folder.

[image: android studio]

Second, Create the same structure with a package name of a class.

for example, picture blow, you will have the same folder structure if you have a Tobee.class in a com.tobee package.

You can read a file in a Tobee class by calling a getResource or getResourceAsStream method.

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("jar_properties");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have solved the issue: pack everything in a jar including resource files then import this jar into the Android project.